# Access PowerBI Reports by using AzureAD token

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi

I am new to azureAD and powerBI, I have an angular Application with .net Code apis, I need to access PowerBI reports by using Azure AD login.

Steps i have done so far:

1. Created Azure Active directory account
2. Created Groups and User in same AD
3. Created an Enterprize Account and got tanent ID , Object ID and added return URL
4. Currently with http://localhost:4200 return URL i am getting Token ( AzureAD token) and also authenticating

when i deploy the App on IIS with HTTPS i am getting error "AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'undefined' was not found in the directory 'Default Directory'."  (I have changed return URL same which is according to IIS application name)

With One of user from AzureAD i have created powerBI account and created/Imported PowerBI reports
to view that reports everytime i have to provide credentials of PowerBI

Is there a way that i can use Same token which is generated with AzureAD login credentials

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce in my environment for the powerBi app and got the same error :***

```
{
error": "unauthorized_client", 
 "error_description": "AADSTS700016: Application with identifier xxx-06623xx34' was not found in the directory 'Contoso'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant
}
```

When I tried to authenticate using postman

[image]

- It is because the ClientId value is incorrect.
- I have given It the ID of client secret :

[image]

- It must be the application id of the app.

[image]

***After correcting I could authenticate successfully***

[image]